# my task is to write a method that takes 2 arrays containing doubles and takes the larger of the two numbers at each index and returns them

Tags: java

Write   a   method  that    takes   two arrays  containing  doubles and returns a   new array
that    contains    the larger of   the two values  at  each    index.  The method  should  handle
cases   in  which   one array   is  longer  than    the other. I'm not really sure how to go about this, So far I have this in the main:

```
 public static void main(String[] args){

 double[] test1 = {3.3, 8.2, 19.0, 38.1, 2.1, 3.7};
 double[] test2 = {4.8, 2.1, 27.3, 6.0};
 double[] maxResult = maximize(test1, test2);
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(test1));
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(test2));
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(maxResult));
  }
```

the output I'm trying to get is:

```
  [3.3, 8.2, 19.0, 38.1, 2.1, 3.7]
  [4.8, 2.1, 27.3, 6.0]
  [4.8, 8.2, 27.3, 38.1, 2.1, 3.7]
```

I don't know what to put inside the method to have it take the larger of the two arrays.

Comment: Have you made any attempt at what the `maximize` function might look like that isn't working?  As posted this seems like you pasted your homework question into StackOverflow.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because: "[3. Questions asking for homework help must include a **summary of the work you've done so far** to solve the problem, and a **description of the difficulty you are having** solving it.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)". Current state of your question doesn't fulfill these requirements. Consider using [edit] option to improve your question (or be ready to see it closed/deleted).

Comment: my method has errors that's why I didn't add it in.. embarrasment :( @KevinDiTraglia

Comment: @Progamminnoob Don't be embarrassed, you are likely closer to the correct answer than you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static double[] maximize(double[] test1, double[] test2) {
    double[] maxValues = new double[Math.max(test1.length, test2.length)];
    for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(test1.length, test2.length); i++) {
        maxValues[i] = Math.max(test1[i], test2[i]);
    }
    if (test1.length < test2.length) {
        for (int i = test1.length; i < test2.length; i++) {
            maxValues[i] = test2[i];
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = test2.length; i < test1.length; i++) {
            maxValues[i] = test1[i];
        }
    }
    return maxValues;
}
```